# Inserting document title in the header using the titleps package while combined with the titlesec package

Tags: titlesec

When I use only the `titleps` package, the following code works and puts the document title in the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titleps} 
\usepackage{duckuments}

\title{A friendly duck}
\author{Duck}
\date{\today}

\newpagestyle{myFancy}[\normalsize\bfseries]{
    \setheadrule{0.4pt}%
    \sethead[\thetitle][][]%
            {\thetitle}{}{}%
}
\pagestyle{myFancy}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I combine the `titleps` package with the `titlesec` package using the command `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`, the output is not as expected. It puts 'section no' in one header and 'subsection no' in another.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{duckuments}

\title{A friendly duck}
\author{Duck}
\date{\today}

\newpagestyle{myFancy}[\normalsize\bfseries]{
    \setheadrule{0.4pt}%
    \sethead[\thetitle][][]%
            {\thetitle}{}{}%
}
\pagestyle{myFancy}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \duckument
\end{document}
```

2nd page

[image]

3rd page

[image]

It can be solved by directly inserting the title in the `\newpagestyle` command like this:

```
\newpagestyle{myFancy}[\normalsize\bfseries]{
    \setheadrule{0.4pt}%
    \sethead[A friendly duck][][]%
            {A friendly duck}{}{}%
}
```

But it would be great to have a solution using something like `\thetitle`.

Comment: Both `titling` and `titlesec` are defining `\thetitle`, and therefore they aren’t fully compatible.

Comment: @JavierBezos Is there any `\thetitle` equivalent in the `titlesec` package?

Comment: Nope, I’m sorry. `titlesec` deals with sectioning titles, not cover titles.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/46#issue-1085144823